# Best way to read line into singly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to figure out how to implement a singly linked list using C, with nodes storing pointes to strings (lines in a file). I guess this won't work because "line_buffer" gets overwritten, but I don't see any immediate solution. Any ideas?

```
struct line {
    char* string;
    struct line* next;
};

int main(void) {
    ...
    (open file to f)
    ...

    struct line* first = (struct line*) malloc(sizeof(struct line));
    first->string = "string0";
    struct line* current = first;

    char line_buffer[256];

    while (fgets(line_buffer, sizeof(line_buffer), f)) {
        struct line* newl = (struct line*) malloc(sizeof(struct line));
        newl->string = line_buffer;
        current->next = newl;
        current = newl;

        j++;
    }        

    current->next = NULL;

    struct line* temp = first;

    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", temp->string);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
string0
whatever in last line
whatever in last line
whatever in last line
```

Comment: whats the point of `j++;` ? :D

Comment: If you're prepared to malloc a new `struct line` every time, why are you so reluctant to malloc a new buffer?

Comment: `newl->string = line_buffer;` --> `newl->string = strdup(line_buffer);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `strcpy()` function.

Instead of:

```
newl->string = line_buffer;
```

Put:

```
strcpy(newl->string, line_buffer);
```

Mind you, this is just a suggestion of a quick fix to your code, there are better ways of implementing this logic.

Here is a [**great guide**](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/105/LinkedListProblems.pdf)

Also you could write a simple `insert` function to separate your logic (inserting at the list head)

```
struct line* insertFront(struct line *head, char *string) {
    struct line *newl = malloc(sizeof(struct line));
    newl->string = (char*) malloc(strlen(string)+1);
    if(head == NULL) {           
        strcpy(newl->string, string);
        newl->next = NULL;
        head = newl;
    } else {
        strcpy(newl->string, string);
        newl->next = head;
        head = newl;
    }
    return head;
}
```

You would use this function in your code like:

```
int main(void) {
    ...
    (open file to f)
    ...

    struct line* first = NULL;    
    char line_buffer[256];

    while (fgets(line_buffer, sizeof(line_buffer), f)) {
        first = insertFront(first, line_buffer);
    }        

    struct line* temp = first;    
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", temp->string);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use a pointer in the node. 
// newl->string = line_buffer;
memcpy(newl->string, line_buffer, strlen(line_buffer)+1); 
causes segmentation fault though..